# How to move multiple picture boxes when clicked VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I will have 30 different picture boxes on a form, and I am using the arrow keys on the keyboard to move these. However I don't know how to move multiple picture boxes using the code I have. Ideally I would like to move one at a time when clicked on, here is the code I have to move picture boxes:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left 'Left Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
            Me.PictureBox1.Left -= 1
        Case Keys.Up 'Up Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
            Me.PictureBox1.Top -= 1
        Case Keys.Right 'Right Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
            Me.PictureBox1.Left += 1
        Case Keys.Down 'Down Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
            Me.PictureBox1.Top += 1
    End Select
End Sub
```

How do I move one of 30 picture boxes individually when clicked on?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a class level variable of type `PictureBox`.
This variable should hold a reference to the last PicrureBox clicked by the user.
Then all you have to do is change the KeyDown code you already have to move the class level variable.

```
' on the form level
dim CurrentPictureBox As PictureBox

' use the same Click event for all PictureBoxes to populate this variable:
CurrentPictureBox = Cast(Sender, PictureBox)


' Change your existing code:
if not CurrentPictureBox is nothing then
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.Left 'Left Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
        CurrentPictureBox.Left -= 1
    Case Keys.Up 'Up Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
        CurrentPictureBox .Top -= 1
    Case Keys.Right 'Right Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
        CurrentPictureBox .Left += 1
    Case Keys.Down 'Down Arrow Key to move picture boxes left
        CurrentPictureBox.Top += 1
End Select
end if
```

**Note:** Code written directly here, and also it's been a while since my VB.Net days. there might be some mistakes in the code but the idea is the important thing.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information, what code is needed to change the KeyDown event to move the class level variable? I have little experience with VB at the moment

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up having to make a few changes to the CurrentPictureBox sender, but its all working now. Thank you!